# A calculator app on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Can anyone please explain the difference between this

```
[display setText:[[display text] stringByAppendingString:digit ]];
```

and this

```
[display setText:digit];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is rather clear. But if you don't understand:

Here `[display setText:[[display text] stringByAppendingString:digit ]];` a new digit will be added to the digits currently displaying on the screen. This `BOOL` value `userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber` is extremely straightforward - it is said that there are always digits on the screen and a new digit must be added to them. This method `stringByAppendingString` returns a new string made by appending a given digit to the currently displayed digits in the `UITextField`.

And here `[display setText:digit];` all the text which are displayed in the `UITextField` will be overwritten  with a new digit value. But as I suppose it is used when there are no digits on the screen and we need to write the first one.I don't know what is using for displaying digits in that app. But if it is `UITextField` then using `setText` is a bad idea - it is a  deprecated method. You should use `text` property instead.

This is an extremely simple code which you need to understand yourself. So my advice you to read some introductory books on CocoaTouch and iOS with simple examples there are plenty of them: [http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-iOS-Development-Exploring-SDK/dp/1430245123/ref=pd_sim_b_8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430245123) . And don't forget to use official documentation.

Comment: Your answer is much explaining about what I needed to know. Thanks a lot